# Installing Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, sdk, ide

I wish to install Android Studio for Android Development instead of Eclipse on my Windows 7 PC. I wish to keep Eclipse installed, but I need help deciding which bundle of Android Studio to install.

Can I just install **android-studio-ide-141.1980579-windows.exe (No SDK tools included)** from [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other)? Or do I need to install the entire bundle (**android-studio-bundle-141.1980579-windows.exe**)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may install android-studio-ide-141.1980579-windows.exe (No SDK tools included) and configure to use the same SDK that your Eclipse does.

In Android Studio setup will pop up a window SDK Components Setup and you may fill the SDK path in Android SDK Location

Answer (score 0):

android-studio-bundle-141.1980579-windows.exe

Downloading Studio With Sdk tools will help u .

You dont need to select which tools to download , u will get all the latest tools in second one !

So Preferably download Android studio with sdk tools included .

Thanks